# How to find location/path to ruby sass file on eclipse builder?

Tags: css, ruby, eclipse, sass, builder

Im willing to setup sass builder on my PC win Eclipse. I struggle to find right Location for Ruby sass file. I installed Ruby per description.

https://pasteboard.co/IsYsqT9.png

Is there some command in CMD to find that path which would start with usr or user?
If I give a path starting with D://.. builder doesnt work.
Thanks!